# rxjs emit only at specific intervals

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I would like to call a function only at specific intervals of time, specifically 3 and 6 seconds, and am having some difficulty finding the correct operator to use.

bufferTime seemed like a good candidate, but the array it outputs isn't what I would expect.

Here's a short example:

```js
summarize(): void {
  const responseInterval = interval(1000);
  const responseIntervalObservable = responseInterval.pipe(bufferTime(1000));

  responseIntervalObservable.subscribe(intervalValue => {
    console.log('intervalValue', intervalValue);
  });
}
```

This outputs:

```bash
intervalValue []
intervalValue [0, 1]
intervalValue [2]
intervalValue [3]
intervalValue [4]
intervalValue [5]
intervalValue [6]
intervalValue [7]
intervalValue [8]
```

I was hoping to see something like `[1], [2], [3]` so I could call a function specifically at 3 seconds and again at 6 seconds.

What is the correct, or better operator to use?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you could provide a stackblitz with an observable that emits some random value or explain somehow for a given input what's the expected output, that might help

Comment: Your desired behavior isn't clear.  You want to emit at 3000ms and 6000ms, what about after that?  It seems like doing `bufferTime(3000)` would get you part way there, but not sure of the behavior you want after 6000ms.

Comment: I have a potentially long-running HTTP call in an Angular app. After 3 seconds and 6 seconds, I would like to update messaging to the user. After 6 seconds, or the request completes, the subscription can be cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using `interval` rather than putting bufferTime in-bewteen. That emits a zero-based index for the iteration rather than an array.

Then I can just check the index for a specific value until the request is complete or times out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is overkill or not, but you could do something like this.

Our watcher does the following:

- Filter only `2` and `5` (because it is `0` based)
- Do something with the value (just log to console in this example)
- Filter the interval for `5`
- take the first item
- Cancel the http request (just log to the console for the example)
- finalize (optional) just to show that this was complete

The http request does the following:

- Take until the watcher completes (`take(1)` is called)

```js
const watcher = interval(1000).pipe(
  filter((i) => i === 2 || i === 5),
  tap((i) => console.log(i + 1, 'seconds have passed')),
  filter((i) => i === 5),
  take(1),
  finalize(() => console.log('Watcher Complete'))
);

// An example long running process (such as an http request).
fromFetch('https://example.com')
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(watcher),
    finalize(() => console.log('Http Request Canceled'))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-wather-for-http-request?file=index.ts).

Comment: Great example. I'm sure this will come in handy someday. For what I needed to do, it's a lot more code than what I ended up with, but thank you.